# I want to save data in table Cydata. But I have a mistake on @cydata = Cydata.new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Help me! I want to save data in table Cydata. But I have a mistake on

```
  def new
    @cydata = Cydata.new
  end
```

**Mistake**

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "cydata" does not exist LINE 5: WHERE a.attrelid = '"cydata"'::regclass ^ : SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum WHERE a.attrelid = '"cydata"'::regclass AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped ORDER BY a.attnum
```

**Models**

```
class Cydata < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :year
end

class Year < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cydatas
  has_many :courses, :through => :cydatas
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cydatas
  has_many :years, :through => :cydatas
end
```

**Controller**

```
class CydatasController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_cydata, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  def index
    @cydatas = Cydata.all
  end

  def new
    @cydata = Cydata.new
  end


  def create
    @years = Year.all
    @courses = Course.all
    Cydata.transaction do
      @cydata = Cydata.new(cydata_params)

        respond_to do |format|
          if @cydata.save?

            format.html { redirect_to @cydata, notice: 'Cydata was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @cydata }
          else
            format.html { render action: 'new' }
            format.json { render json: @cydata.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity  }

          end
          end

        end



    end



  private
  def set_cydata
    @cydata = Cydata.find(params[:id])
  end



  def cydata_params
    params.require(:cydata).permit(:year_id, :course_id, :kolvo_studentov)
  end

end
```

Comment: have you created a migration after creating the `Cydata` class and adding it's relations to the other classes ?

Comment: Please add the code around this line where you are having issues, as well as any relevant stacktrace for an error that we can use to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate and populate a migration. Please check the [guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) on this matter

```
$ rails generate migration createCydata
```

and then edit the generated file and run:

```
$ rake db:migrate
```